# Missing Realm Constructor

Tags: realm

[image]

I am currently developing on a an android emulator using Realm as a local DB and I get 'Missing Realm Constructor, did you run pod install (on an android emulator !!). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using windows,Linux or mac as you're dev system?

Comment: Make sure you are using `react-native cli` as __realm__ doesn't work with _expo_. Docs says it here https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/install/

Comment: @NicolaMunzslimxshady I am working on a windows system.